# Does anyone know of an upside down window border or theme for MATE or Gnome?

Tags: themes, window-buttons, layout

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this but I have been wondering if you could have an upside down window border. What I mean by this is can you move the close, minimise, maximise, etc... buttons down to the bottom of a window. I have done some goggling and, for the most part, I can only find ways to move the buttons from the left side to the right or vice versa.

I could be asking for a bit too much but if anyone either knows how to move the buttons (or the whole top bar) down to the bottom of a window or if a theme already exists with this layout I would be thankful if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: After looking around a bit, I think what I'm looking for is to move the title bar down to the bottom of the window.

Comment: In what desktop environment? Unity? Gnome? Cinnamon? Something else?

Comment: I'm looking at MATE right now but I think Gnome would be easier to find info about.

Comment: I am 100% certain it is doable. How much effort for it? well, its not a default theme so if you’re lucky rewriting a theme would do it. if not, it could be much more involved

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify which desktop environment(s) you are interested in. Answers will depend on it.

Comment: try editing mate themes. or git on the git hub page, and ask there:https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-themes

Comment: I'll give that a try

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenu.html#GtkMenuPositionFunc  this might be related.